# Asymptotics of the incomplete gamma function

Tags: integration, asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function

Consider the following integral
$$I=\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,\beta\right)=\int\limits _{\beta}^{+\infty}t^{-\alpha}e^{-t}dt,$$
where $\alpha,\beta>0$, and $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function. Is it possible to find an asymptotic estimate of $I$ for $\beta\ll\alpha$?

Comment: Integrating py part you get $I=\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\beta^{1-\alpha}e^{-\beta}-\frac{1}{(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}\beta^{2-\alpha}e^{-\beta}+\frac{1}{(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)(3-\alpha)}\beta^{3-\alpha}e^{-\beta}-+...$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\lambda> 0$ and $\beta  = \lambda (\alpha  - 1)$. Then
$$
\Gamma (1 - \alpha ,\beta ) \sim \frac{{\beta ^{1 - \alpha } \mathrm{e}^{ - \beta } }}{{\alpha  - 1}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{p_n (\lambda )}}{{(\lambda  + 1)^{2n + 1} }}\frac{1}{{(\alpha  - 1)^n }}} 
$$
as $\alpha\to+\infty$ uniformly in $\lambda > 0$. Here $p_0(\lambda)=1$ and
$$
p_n (\lambda ) = \lambda (1 + \lambda )p'_{n - 1} (\lambda ) - (2n - 1)\lambda p_{n - 1} (\lambda )
$$
for $n\geq 1$. These are polynomials in $\lambda$ of degree $n$.

To achive the best numerical accuracy, stop the series after about $\left\lfloor {\alpha \sqrt {(\lambda  + \log \lambda  + 1)^2  + \pi ^2 } } \right\rfloor$ terms. See [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1111/sapm.12077) for more details.